# how to merge tree nodes into one node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

Hopefully, my question is not duplicated.
I would like to know if there exists such algorithm which merges some nodes in a tree to a new tree so the node in the new tree consists of some nodes in the old tree?

In order to explain my idea, I drew a graph to explain the question.

Input:  A original tree.

Output: A new tree. There are  following conditions with which the new tree must be satisfied:

1. The number of nodes in the new tree should be a fixed number *k*.
2. Each node in the new tree must consists of nodes in the original tree.  For example, the node A in the second graph contains node 1,3, and 4 of the first graph. Node D in the secod graph contains nodes 9,12, and 13 in the first graph.
3. if one node of the original tree is contained in a node of the new tree, it cannot appear in another node of the new tree.
4. The nodes in the new tree are not necessarily have to be a subtree of the original tree. For example, node C in the second graph contains 6,7,and 10 of the first graph, It is not a subtree of the original graph. Because both node 6 and node 7 in the original graph connect to the nodes in the dotted area of A in the original tree, So they could be grouped in the node C of the second graph.

Currently, I just want the original tree can be converted to a new tree that has a *K* number of nodes and meets above conditions. For a given tree, there are many solutions. For example, graph 3 and graph 4 illustrate another solution for the original tree. It also has 4 nodes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean by `new tree consists of some nodes in the old tree`, so this may or may not be what you seek: [Graph rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_rewriting). If you could explain in more detail by providing data in the nodes it would be helpful to those trying to help. Also, do all of the nodes have the same data, are there rules for merging the data, is there a normal or canonical form for the trees, etc. If this is something off of the top of your head and something you are guessing at then please state as such in your question.

Comment: That was not an answer but a guess; seriously please provide more detail so that I can see if my guess is the answer, and if so I can post an answer that will help the community and you. Remember this is a community forum to help everyone.

Comment: OK, I am trying to state my question clearer.

Comment: Also when you respond to someone other than the original OP of the question or answer you need to add @name to the post so that they see it. I only happen to see your comment because I was here at the moment. If I was not here I would have never seen it. See: [How do comment at-replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @GuyCoder I rewrite my question, I hope it is clear now

Comment: Thanks for using @-reply. Nice that you added details, but I don't see an explanation that helps in writing code. How are the nodes selected to be part of a new tree? `C` is not a subtree, it has two lines coming in from above. How is it decided how many nodes are put into a subtree? Where should the subtrees begin and end?

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you for your comment, I will edit my question again to answer your new question.

Comment: Take some time and think about this, e.g. and day or more if necessary. Do lots of examples with pen and paper and make sure that your explanation is clear enough for a person learning programming to understand. As I often say, I am not a mind reader.

Comment: @GuyCoder OK, Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This is still very unclear. Please write down how to convert the old tree into the new true using if-then rules, e.g. [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)). Your declarative description is not clear enough for me to understand. Also what is your skill level at programming: Self taught no schooling, or have a degree, or no schooling but work in the field, etc.

Comment: As this is turning into a discussion, I don't plan to respond any more today and if I remember will take a look at it tomorrow. I am only spending time on this one because it looked like it presented an opportunity to give an answer using graph-rewriting which is not something I recall ever seeing here at StackOverflow. However if the question can not be answered with graph rewriting I will move on, which at present is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need an addition condition or desired property of your output, otherwise it is quite trivial:

- Starting from leaf nodes, copy `K - 1` nodes to the output: `B = {11}, C = {12}, D = {13}`
- Group all other nodes into a single `K-th` node: `A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if I find this question is trivial, I will delete it